# How to reinstate "playback speed" control in WMP?

Tags: windows-7, windows, speed, windows-media-player, video-playback

I've recently reinstalled Windows 7 and been watching movies via out-of-box Windows Media Player (with all out-of-box codecs). In particular, i liked WMP's ability to change playback speed. Recently, I've installed K-Lite Codec Pack (Mega) and "playback speed" control work no longer (menu disabled, no slider in Enhancements).

This happens with all videos of Xvid AVI format.

I've tried already K-Lite's Filter Tweaker utility and changed preferred video decoder from LAV (K-Lite's) back to Microsoft's but the problem still persists. (Change confirmed by Filter Studio apps, also it reports what audio decoder is MS, too)

What I can do else besides dropping WMP at all? Please advise.

Comment: It's generally not recommended to install any codec packs. If you uninstall K-Lite again, does that fix the issue?